# Why when I import CSV file into MySQL rows are cut off after keywords?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, keyword

I am trying to import a csv file with following sample row:

```
//,/Dona Paula Estate Malbec/,/Malbec from Argentina, South America/,
```

into MySQL database, but everything after "from" is skipped in the table.
I think it is because from is an SQL keyword. Enclosing fields into '/' does not help. Can anyone help me with this? I would really appresiate it!

Table  Wine (wineID, wineName, wineDescription); WineID is the primary key (AutoNmber).

My SQL statement is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Wines.csv' INTO TABLE Wines
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '/'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(wineID, wineName, wineDescription);
```

Comment: What's the schema for table Wines?

Comment: make sure your `wineDescription` field has required data type length assigned.

Comment: Those fields are varChar(255), and the description differs, but every time words are cut off after "from" (including it), so I believe the problem is in the keyword.

Comment: Maybe you could easily do a test and remove the 'from' keyword and see if it works then. Or change it into 'fros' or something. That would provide good insight into the issue...